# ' to find' and 'to develop' can be synonyms?

Tags: meaning-in-context

My textbook give me the next example sentence:

> They're in research and development. They **find** new products for the company to sell.

But I can't see clear the meaning of 'find' in this sentence and I think it's better to use 'develop' instead of 'find':

> They're in research and development. They **develop** new products for the company to sell.

Am I right according to the meaning 'research and development'?
Or 'to find' has the meaning 'to develop' as well?

Answer (score 2):

In these examples:
*find* means they are looking for the new products. It does not by itself specify whether they found any or not.

*develop* means they are making a product, such as starting with an idea, making a prototype, improving it, doing market evaluation and hopefully selling it.

Comment: In other words, there's an implied conditional/volitional: the context implies "they find" is short for "they want to find", "they try to find", "they do work with the intention of finding".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the sentence uses an extended meaning of "find" meaning "discover" or "invent". e.g.

> My team found a very effective anti-cancer chemical this month.

The implication is that all products exist as Platonic ideals -- they just have to be found.